VS 2022 - Source control provider errors
I'm using git for my source control in VS 2022.
Using Azure Dev Ops GIT
I continue to see this error:

I tried to update my csproj file with this:
From:
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>

To
<SccProjectName></SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath></SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath></SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider></SccProvider>

That did not resolve the issue.
I'm going to my Win 11 task bar, clicking VS 2022, going to my quick reference project and opening.
Here is my VS 2022 version:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.10.4
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.10.4+35027.167
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032
Installed Version: Professional
UPDATE 1: (per suggestion)
I removed these lines 100%:
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>

I still receive the error when I go via:
Task bar -> Recent projects -> Select project -> error occurs
Another way:
Do not use the task bar -> Open VS 2022 -> Go to File -> Recent Projects and Solutions -> Select my project solution -> Error DOES NOT occur.
Not sure what the difference is?

The <Scc...> MSBuild properties aren't used by git, so you can just remove them entirely. Also, is Git selected in Tools > Options > Source Control? (Note that if you use Git hosted by Azure DevOps (neé TFS) then you should still select Git and not TFS (the TFS option is for when you're using TFS' deprecated SVN-style source-control).

@Dai: yes, we use Azure DevOps Git! I'll try to remove it 100% and let you know. Thank you for your response/help.

@Dai: Made an update. Error still occurs one way, but via File and not the task bar, the error doesn't show?

@Dai: Also Git was selected in: Tools > Options > Source Control

Please check similar ticket here, it was reported as a Visual Studio bug. You can choose yes to remove the SCC bindings, save the changes, and then close and try again.

@wadezhou-MSFT: Yes, I saw this link first and tried those. It still did not work. It seems to only occur when opening via Taskbar via Recent items. If you open up VS 2022 and then go to File etc., then it works fine.

@wadezhou-MSFT: I'm going to try this again to see if it resolves it this time. I did this earlier this AM, checked into dev ops, ran the pipeline. Then it seemed to work a couple of times for me. Then my co-worker pulled down my change and they were still seeing the issue.

It's an issue from Visual studio, so your co-worker could also need to choose yes when the dialog appears, and save to fix on local. Please also make sure Git was selected in: Tools > Options > Source Control.
